# How to use psycopg2 connection string with variables?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a Postgres Database with variables like this:

```
cs = "dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s",(dn,du,dp,dh,dbp)
con = None
con = psycopg2.connect(cs)
```

However I get the error message:

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be string, not tuple
```

I need to be able to use variables in the connection string. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17):

Your code currently creates a tuple with your string and the tuple you are trying to sub. You need:

```
cs = "dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s" % (dn,du,dp,dh,dbp)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass params directly without building connection string:

```py
con = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=dn,
    user=du,
    password=dp,
    host=dh,
    port=dbp,
)
```

[Docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect) for more details on `psycopg2.connect`